# Difference between Constants and Direct addressing in x86 addressing modes

Tags: assembly, x86

I would like to know the difference between the assembly code when using operands for addressing modes. Example
mov ax, 25 // where 25 is considered as a constant
mov ax, [1000] // [1000] is considered as a memory location

My question is, are the difference between constants and memory location because of the square bracket[1000] or is there something else. And is mov(opcode) a part of the cpu instruction set? 
Will be grateful for some answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your assembler you have to use the appropriate syntax so it can differentiate between a constant and a memory location. Some assemblers use the syntax you showed, some assemblers require `$` prefix for immediates, some assemblers use `ptr`, etc. Consult your assembler's documentation.

`mov` is a mnemonic, which has different machine code representations depending on the operands. For example the the `mov ax, 25` that you used is actually `mov r16, imm16` having opcode `B8`. The `mov ax, [1000]` can be `mov ax, moffs16` having opcode `A1`. See the instruction set reference.

Comment: Thank you @Jester, finally I understood opcode and mnemonic, the assembler used in the book that I am referring is using MASM.